# Generate winnable solitaire games with a randomness equivalent to shuffling

Tags: algorithm, random, shuffle

If you are given:

1. A good shuffling algorithm (a good source of randomness plus a method of shuffling not subject to any of the common pitfalls which would bias the result)
2. A magic function `WINNABLE(D)` which takes the shuffled deck and returns True if the deck `D` is winnable by some playing sequence, or False if it inevitably results in a losing position.

then it would be possible to generate a set of "well distributed" winnable solitaire deals by generating a large set of starting decks with (1) and then filtering them down to the winnable set with (2).  This method of randomly generating possibilities and picking from them is always a good starting point when you're trying to avoid having subtle selection bias creep in to your result.

The problem with this is that (2) is hard (maybe NP-hard depending on the game) and even approximations of it are computationally expensive (if you're on an iPad, say).  However, cheaper algorithms such as starting from a winning position and making random "un-moves" to reverse the game back to a starting point may have biases toward particular deck shuffles that are very hard to quantify or avoid.

Are there any interesting algorithms or research in the area of generating winnable games like this?

Comment: I usually go about this in reverse; from a solved position I generate random mutations until I reach a starting point with a given 'complexity' (level). **[Simon Tatham's puzzle collection](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/puzzles/) also has many generative algorithms that generates solvable cases of _peg solitaire_, _mine field_, _inertia_, etc. etc. You could look at his problem generators.

Answer (score 0):

Since solitaire games vary so much, reasoning at this level of generality is itself hard. To focus our ideas, let's take a particular example: Forty Thieves. It's a double-pack game starting with empty foundations, to be built ace-upwards; an empty waste pile; and a layout of ten pre-dealt face-up piles of four cards each. The top cards of the waste and layout piles are *exposed*. At each move, you can:

1. Move an exposed card to its legal place in a foundation, no worrying
   back;
2. Move an exposed card onto a pile in the layout, only legal when
   building downwards in the same suit;
3. Move an exposed card to an empty layout slot;
4. Deal a card from stock to the top of the waste.

A beginner plays these options in the order stated. (The implementation I play actually has a hint button that suggests a move accordingly.) I estimate that fewer than one in ten deals are winnable by that strategy, whereas the actual proportion of winnable deals is about one in three.

Now if you generate winnable deals by random un-moves, there is a hard-to-quantify bias; I don't disagree with that. I think, though, that the deals will tend to be harder than average among deals that happen to be winnable, with almost no deals winnable by the beginner's strategy.

You can, however, deliberately make the un-moves non-random. If you select un-moves in the opposite order to a beginner's strategy, you get a deal on which the beginner's strategy works: e.g. if only as a last resort you un-move from a foundation to waste, then moving from waste to a foundation whenever possible is always right.

Answer (score -4):

Hmm, I don't know much about Solitaire but this is how I would tackle the problem. See my pseudo code.

//Assuming you have created a "card" object.

```
Generate a List<Cards> deck;// A list populated with every card in deck that you can use in Solitaire with the number of each card you can use in Solitaire.
Generate a List<Cards> table;
while(deck.size()>0){//This is the real code.
     table.add(deck.remove((int)(Math.random()*deck.size())));
}
//And done. You know have a perfectly shuffled list of Cards in table.
//Now divide the list up however you want.
```

I have no idea for part 2.

Comment: Part 2 is the entire reason this question exists.

Comment: `"If you are given ... A good shuffling algorithm ..."` - a shuffling algorithm is already given, the task is not to write one.

Comment: To your credit your shuffle is correct, where most people's initial attempts are not. It is too slow, though, because List.remove() is expensive compared to simple indexed access.